# Android saving activity even after stopping the emulator

Tags: android

So as the title suggest, how do I save the activity even after closing or stopping the emulator? For example, if you successfully login using correct creds, if you stop or close the emulator and run it again, it should go back to where you left of--the successful login screen. We're using sharedinstance btw.

Answer (score 0):

In the AndroidManifest file on your aplication, exist a line which determinate what activity is going to open every time that the aplication turn on.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

if you want to change that behavior programatically, you have to check for some conditions which redirect to the desire activity. For example if 
you want to save your login creds to dont have to login again, you have to storage that information on some database or CookieStorage, and check the data every time that aplication turn on.

Comment: What exactly do I add to my program? Apparently my professor wants it to be in the code, like a condition of some sort. And I really don't have any clue because we're still new in Android development.